# Element is going outside the body

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

While creating a responsive menu bar the nav/ul element is going outside the body when changing the display property from flex to block. Element come inside when increasing the height of the header.

[Click here to see the ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57wkP.png)

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #ff702a;
  --bg-color: #1e1c2a;
  --big-font: 4rem;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

header,
ul {
  border: 1px green solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  padding: 0 4rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

header .logo {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.bx.bx-menu {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}

@media(max-width: 425px) {
  header nav ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="logo">FOODIES</a>
    <i class='bx bx-menu' style='color:#ffffff'></i>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Service</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the header height is set height: 5rem; try to set height auto or max-content on mobile screens

```css
:root{
    --main-color: #ff702a;
    --bg-color: #1e1c2a;
    --big-font: 4rem;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px red solid;
}

header, ul{
    border: 1px green solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
header{
    padding: 0 4rem;
    height: 5rem;
}
header .logo{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.bx.bx-menu{
    display: none;
}
nav ul li{
    margin: 1rem;
    list-style: none;
}


@media(max-width: 425px){
    header nav ul{
        display: block;
    }
header{
    height: max-content;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">FOODIES</a>
        <i class='bx bx-menu' style='color:#ffffff'  ></i>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>Service</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

**Or**  Set overflow scroll to the header

```
@media(max-width: 425px){
    header{
    overflow-y: scroll;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nav get inside the body. But, i want the nav to cover the whole screen so i change nav position to ' absolute ' and assign 100% width and some height, now getting the error again.

Comment: please upload screenshot what design you want on mobile

Comment: Something like this
[link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ijpz1uG9AhlWHO8PCWiZ7lZN9VkH1EI3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this drive link need access to check the data

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ijpz1uG9AhlWHO8PCWiZ7lZN9VkH1EI3/view?usp=sharing